# How do I simplify $4\sin(2a) - 2\sin(2a) \cdot 4\sin^2(a)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> $4\sin(2a) - 2\sin(2a) \cdot 4\sin^2(a)$

How do I simplify the above expression by using double-angle identities and half-angle identities? I could not find a way to solve the problem and have tried these methods but I just can't seem to find a way.

I've gotten $8\sin(x)\cos(x)(1-2\sin^2x)$ which would be simplified to $8\sin(x)\cos(x)\cos(2x)$. Apparently, the answer is $2\sin(4x)$, but I just get $4\sin(2x)(1-2\sin^2x)$.

Comment: Could you mind showing what you have tried otherwise your question might be closed. You can edit the question by clicking on edit button

Comment: First, factor out $4\sin 2x$. Second, use $1-2\sin^2x=\cos 2x$. Finally, use $2\sin x\cos x=\sin 2x$. Done.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you for self-answering your question, but unfortunately your answer was deleted because it was squished into a small space, which made it hard to read. Next time you write an answer, consider spreading it out on multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

Proceed by using
$$1-2\sin^2\theta=\cos2\theta$$
and
$$2\sin\theta\cos\theta=\sin2\theta$$

Try using this. Hope it helps :)